# Link to native app when user get facebook app request

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am implementing facebook app request concept in my app. For that I have used this code [Facebook app request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/#step3)

When user send the request to friends who are enabled in iOS device. It is working fine. Friends are getting proper notification. But I also need that when user click on that notification, it should open my iOS native app. Anyone has an idea about this?
How to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "deep linking" here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/link-to-your-native-app-ios-sdk/

You will need to 
- add a url scheme
- set up a facebook app
- add the correct info from your facebook app into your Info.plist
- add the code from the examples.

I followed the facebook instructions and there are a lot of steps. But it works for me.

I hope this helps!